# Смена DIV при смене слайдера

Tags: javascript, css

Есть сайт со слайдером:

```
         <div class="item vimeo" data-video-start="4">
            <video autoplay muted loop>
               <source src="/видео.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
         </div>
         <div class="item vimeo">
            <video autoplay muted controls>
               <source src="/видео-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
         </div>
      </section>
```

Под ним есть два div блока, которые находятся друг под другом:

```
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               Первый блок
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
               Второй блок
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Нужно сделать смену этих блоков при смене слайдера. Допустим если на экране первый слайдер, то первым должен стоять Первый блок, а под ним второй и т.п.

```
         iframes = slideWrapper.find('.embed-player'),
         lazyImages = slideWrapper.find('.slide-image'),
         lazyCounter = 0;
 
         // POST commands to YouTube or Vimeo API
         function postMessageToPlayer(player, command){
         if (player == null || command == null) return;
         player.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(command), "*");
         }
 
         // When the slide is changing
         function playPauseVideo(slick, control){
         var currentSlide, slideType, startTime, player, video;
 
         currentSlide = slick.find(".slick-current");
         slideType = currentSlide.attr("class").split(" ")[1];
         player = currentSlide.find("iframe").get(0);
         startTime = currentSlide.data("video-start");
 
         if (slideType === "vimeo") {
            switch (control) {
               case "play":
               if ((startTime != null && startTime > 0 ) && !currentSlide.hasClass('started')) {
                  currentSlide.addClass('started');
                  postMessageToPlayer(player, {
                     "method": "setCurrentTime",
                     "value" : startTime
                  });
               }
               postMessageToPlayer(player, {
                  "method": "play",
                  "value" : 0
               });
               break;
               case "pause":
               postMessageToPlayer(player, {
                  "method": "pause",
                  "value": 0
               });
               break;
            }
         } else if (slideType === "video") {
            video = currentSlide.children("video").get(0);
            if (video != null) {
               if (control === "play"){
               video.play();
               } else {
               video.pause();
               }
            }
         }
         }
 
         // Resize player
         function resizePlayer(iframes, ratio) {
         if (!iframes[0]) return;
         var win = $(".main-slider"),
               width = win.width(),
               playerWidth,
               height = win.height(),
               playerHeight,
               ratio = ratio || 16/9;
 
         iframes.each(function(){
            var current = $(this);
            if (width / ratio < height) {
               playerWidth = Math.ceil(height * ratio);
               current.width(playerWidth).height(height).css({
               left: (width - playerWidth) / 2,
                  top: 0
               });
            } else {
               playerHeight = Math.ceil(width / ratio);
               current.width(width).height(playerHeight).css({
               left: 0,
               top: (height - playerHeight) / 2
               });
            }
         });
         }
 
         // DOM Ready
         $(function() {
         // Initialize
         slideWrapper.on("init", function(slick){
            slick = $(slick.currentTarget);
            setTimeout(function(){
               playPauseVideo(slick,"play");
            }, 1000);
            resizePlayer(iframes, 16/9);
         });
         slideWrapper.on("beforeChange", function(event, slick) {
            slick = $(slick.$slider);
            playPauseVideo(slick,"pause");
         });
         slideWrapper.on("afterChange", function(event, slick) {
            slick = $(slick.$slider);
            playPauseVideo(slick,"play");
         });
         slideWrapper.on("lazyLoaded", function(event, slick, image, imageSource) {
            lazyCounter++;
            if (lazyCounter === lazyImages.length){
               lazyImages.addClass('show');
               // slideWrapper.slick("slickPlay");
            }
         });
 
         //start the slider
         slideWrapper.slick({
            // fade:true,
            autoplaySpeed:4000,
            lazyLoad:"progressive",
            speed:600,
            arrows:false,
            dots:true,
            cssEase:"cubic-bezier(0.87, 0.03, 0.41, 0.9)"
         });
         });
 
         // Resize event
         $(window).on("resize.slickVideoPlayer", function(){  
         resizePlayer(iframes, 16/9);
         });
```

По средствами bootstrap, с помощью которого и состоит весь сайт, можно частично решить данный вопрос, подставив нужный класс:

```
<div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               Первый блок
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 order-first">
               Второй блок
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Но как его подставить при нажатии кнопки смены слайдера или когда он перелистывается автоматически.

Comment: И на то и на то

Comment: О чём Вы? Ваш комментарий не решает проблему.

Comment: Вы спросили при нажатии или когда он автоматически перелистывается, я и ответил, что ставить надо и при нажатии и когда автоматически перелистывается

Comment: Я спросил не варианты смены, а как сменить css класс у div для их смены расположения на странице.